# iOS Deprecated dataWithContentsOfMappedFile replacement

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsdata

This line of code:

```
let pkcs12Data = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path!)
```

Is showing a warning in XCode 7:

```
'dataWithContentsOfMappedFile' was deprecated in iOS 8.0: Use +dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: and NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe or NSDataReadingMappedAlways instead.
```

But when I try any of the suggested, I can't find any methods responding to suggested. Any idea?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

Should be used as an init method:

```
let pkcs12Data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: options, error: &error)
```

If you are using swift 2.x you should wrap the with a `try-statement`.

Comment: I attempted that, but when we try to cast it as! CFDataRef then I get: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (CODE=EXC_I386_INVOP SUBCODE=0x0)

Comment: @downvoter: It would be helpful to know what is wrong about this answer, so that I can fix it if necessary